# Understanding arcpy.CalculateField_management with Join?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-joins, error-000728

I am using `arcpy.CalculateField_management` to fill a column field with another column values.

I have two shapefiles, `fishnet.shp` and `new_run.shp`. First I joined both using `arcpy.AddJoin_management` as follows:

`arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("fishnet.shp","fishnet_layer")`
`arcpy.AddJoin_management("fishnet_layer","FID","new_run_grid.shp","FID_fishne")`

Now I want to assign fishnet.shp's column `rungrid` the value of the joined table's column `final_run` value.

How to use  `arcpy.CalculateField_management` here?

I tried the following code but it gave error:

`arcpy.CalculateField_management("fishnet_layer","rungrid","!new_run.final_run","PYTHON")`

I am getting the following error:

`ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000728: Field rungrid does not exist within table
Failed to execute (CalculateField).`

Further

I checked the names of the fields of `fishnet_layer` and these two names are there `fishnet.run_grid` and `new_run.final_run`. After giving the following command:

`arcpy.CalculateField_management("fishnet_layer",'fishnet_f.run_grid','new_run_grid.run_grid1',"PYTHON")`

I am getting the following error:

`ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: new_run_grid.run_grid1 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'new_run_grid' is not defined
Failed to execute (CalculateField).`

Comment: Check the field names using: `print [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields("fishnet_layer")]` after join. Maybe you are using the wrong names in Calculate Field

Comment: @BERA I just did it and still got an error,  I have edited the question, pl see

Comment: no time to test today, but I think that you must use the name of the layer, not the name of the table/feature class. So "fishnet_layer.rungrid", and for the second part you still need the !!

Comment: You need to also create a layer of `new_run_grid.shp` and use this in the join. You cant join a shapefile to a layer, both need to be layers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check:

1. You need to create layers of both shapefiles and use in the join. You are only creating one layer at the moment.
2. Make sure you are using the correct field names in calculate field, for example with `print [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields("fishnet_layer")]` after the join

I would use a [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead of trying to join the data and da.UpdateCursor instead of Field Calculator:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\shapefilefolder'

shape_to_update = 'fishnet.shp'
idfield_update = 'FID'
field_to_update = 'rungrid'

shape_to_read = 'new_run_grid.shp'
idfield_read = 'FID_fishne'
field_to_read = 'final_run'

d = {k:v for k,v in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shape_to_read,[idfield_read,field_to_read])}
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shape_to_update,[idfield_update,field_to_update]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in d:
            row[1] = d[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a !

You have "!new_run.final_run"

Should be "!new_run.final_run!"

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a comment on a syntax issue with OP's code.  It does not solve this question.