# Calculate field in a joined table in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, attribute-joins, error-000539

---

### EDIT: I was able to solve the problem with the dictionary approach suggested by @BERA. However, I still don't get why it does not work with the CalculateField method.

I'm trying to calculate a field in a joined table in ArcPy. Code snippet below.

The Calculate Field always gives back the error message:

> ERROR 000539: Invalid field MAX

When I do the same thing manually one after the other in ArcGIS everything works perfectly well.

```
poly_riskobj = r"E:\SRRM_Walldorf\Risikoobjekte.gdb\Ro_Mitte"
out_stat_table = r"E:\SRRM_Walldorf\Risikoobjekte.gdb\Ro_Mitte_HQ100"

arcpy.MakeTableView_management(out_stat_table, "table_view")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(poly_riskobj, "obj_layer")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("obj_layer", "OBJECTID", "table_view", "OBJECTID_1")

arcpy.CalculateField_management(poly_riskobj, "WSP_HQ100", "!MAX!")
```

When I checked the fields with arcpy.ListFields I realized that the joined fields are missing in the poly_riskobj fc I'm refering to in the CalculateField. They only exist in the obj_layer. Which makes sense...
So I adapted the CalculateField to

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("obj_layer", "WSP_HQ100", "!MAX!")
```

and saved it with CopyFeatures. Hoewever, when I check the result in ArcGIS the field "WSP_HQ100" is not updated with the MAX values.

I don't know what I'm missing. I read through these posts but could't figuere it out:

- [Understanding arcpy.CalculateField_management with Join?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315485/understanding-arcpy-calculatefield-management-with-join)
- [How to Calculate Field in joined table using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/how-to-calculate-field-in-joined-table-using-arcpy?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your problem could be the the way you are accessing the table and field names. Try setting [Qualified Field Names environment setting](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/qualified-field-names.htm).

You can try [Join Field](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm) which should be easier/require less code:

> Joins the contents of a table to another table based on a common
> attribute field. The input table is updated to contain the fields from
> the join table. You can select which fields from the join table will
> be added to the input table.

You can also use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) like this, no need for joins:

```
import arcpy

poly_riskobj = r"E:\SRRM_Walldorf\Risikoobjekte.gdb\Ro_Mitte"
out_stat_table = r"E:\SRRM_Walldorf\Risikoobjekte.gdb\Ro_Mitte_HQ100"

#Create a dictionary holding the objectid_1 and maxvalues from out_stat_table
datadict = {oid:maxval for oid,maxval in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_stat_table, ['OBJECTID_1','MAX'])}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(poly_riskobj, ['OBJECTID','WSP_HQ100']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: #For each row in poly_riksobj table
        if row[0] in datadict: #Check if this rows OBJECTID is in the dict
            row[1] = datadict[row[0]] #If so, update row[1]/WSP_HQ100
            cursor.updateRow(row) #"Save"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get what I wanted by using the dictionary approach:

```
import arcpy

poly_riskobj = r"...\Risikoobjekte.gdb\RO_Mitte"

path =  r"...\Risikoobjekte\Risikoobjekte.gdb"

arcpy.env.workspace = r"...\HWGK"
HQ_List1 = arcpy.ListRasters("WSP_" + "*" + "0.tif")
HQ_List2 = arcpy.ListRasters("WSP_" + "*" + "t.tif")
HQ_List = HQ_List1 + HQ_List2
HQ_name_list = ["WSP_HQ10", "WSP_HQ50", "WSP_HQ100", "WSP_HQEXT"]

for index,i in enumerate(HQ_List):
    out_stat_table = path + "\\" + "RO_Mitte_" + HQ_name_list[index]
    
    ZonalStatisticsAsTable(poly_riskobj, "OBJECTID", i, out_stat_table, "DATA", "MIN_MAX_MEAN")
    
    #Create a dictionary holding the objectid_1 and maxvalues from out_stat_table
    datadict = {oid:maxval for oid,maxval in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_stat_table,['OBJECTID_1','MAX'])}

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(poly_riskobj, ['OBJECTID',HQ_name_list[index]]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor: #For each row in poly_riksobj table
            if row[0] in datadict: #Check if this rows OBJECTID is in the dict
                row[1] = round(datadict[row[0]],2) #If so, update row[1]/WSP_HQx
                cursor.updateRow(row) #"Save"
```